# How to use webpack-dev-server for cshtml files in ASP.NET core 6 MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

i use webpack in my asp.net core 6 mvc project.
I use webpack-dev-server to run the browser automatically. My question is, how can I see the changes on index.cshtml instead of index.html. (When I change the extension of the html file from html to cshtml, the browser cannot load the cshtml file)

in webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");

const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin"); 

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        opencv: './wwwroot/Source/example1.js',
    },
    mode: 'development',

    devtool: 'inline-source-map',//baraye modiriate khataha
    devServer: {//jahate webpack-dev-server(hmr bedoobe webpack-hot-middleware )
        static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname,'/wwwroot/distt/' ),
            publicPath: '/devserverdist4/', 
        }, 
        compress: true,
        port: 9003,
        open: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'index1',
        }),     
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'index2',
            filename: 'index2.html',
        }),

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            //filename: "allstyles_for_bonLarma.css",
            filename: '[name].styles.css',
        }),

        new NodePolyfillPlugin(),//taze ezafe baraye erore fs

        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.ASSET_PATH': JSON.stringify(ASSET_PATH),
        }),
    ],
    output: { 
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.join/*resolve*/(__dirname, '/wwwroot/dist/'),
        publicPath:   '/outputdist1/',        
        clean: true,
    },
    
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin(), new CssMinimizerPlugin(),],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader', options: {
                        presets:
                            ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: { //taze ezafe baraye erore fs
        fallback: {
            fs: false,
        },
    }
};
```

I want to use the webpack-dev-server feature in my mvc project views that have cshtml extension

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do that. Razor cshtml file need to have everything include in the view before you build and run your project so that it can build and transform cshtml to html.

`HtmlWebpackPlugin` only work with html so the only option you can choose is serve the html file in your .net core project.

**Update**

You don't need to use webpack-dev-server, it's more convenient to use nuget package:

Add [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation/) NuGet package to the project.

Add the following in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Comment: What is the best way for update project on browser when the javascripts code change in asp.net core?I am really confused between webpack-dev-server, webpack-dev-middleware, webpack-hot-middleware, etc., I would be very grateful if you could help me

Comment: Do you mean to have the app reload in real time? [Webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/) might be able to help you. For more configuration information you can refer to [this link](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/).

Comment: In the tutorial, changes are applied to the .html file, but I want it to be applied to the .cshtml files in the view folder (mvc views)

Comment: Do you mean that after you change cshtml, refreshing the page does not load the content you changed, only re-running the program can load it? @reza

Comment: Yes, I have to write the npm run build command every time that change content. And the npm run start command did not work on cshtml views

Comment: I update my answer, you can have a try. @reza